# Can i register a file descriptor to the Tornado IOLoop

Tags: tornado

I want my IOLoop to listen a file, and when there is any update on this file, IOLoop can call my callback. Please share your code with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IOLoop works with sockets and pipes; it doesn't do anything useful with regular files. A regular file is always "ready" for reads or writes; there is no way to use the IOLoop to watch for changes in the file. (There are platform-specific interfaces like `inotify` that might be used to watch for changes to the file, and you may be able to combine these with the IOLoop, but there is no way to do this with the IOLoop alone)